# Full text Search for pdfs downloaded in my machine In Windows 10?

Tags: search, text-search

I have experience with node.js etc. As well as some knowledge about elastic search. Could you guide me to a book or tutorial that helps me to do it? Or just recommend such a software?

Comment: Can Windows not do that natively yet? It's been in macOS maybe a decade. https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OElf.jpg

Comment: I am not sure about it, I don't think so.

Comment: I only know that the windows search can retrieve the full text of Word documents